# Shell script to find the first and last day of the previous month and pass those values as a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a (separate) curl command and I want to pass it two parameters, the first day of the last month and the last day of the last month. I plan to declare these in a shell script. Could anyone identify how I can get these values using bash? I am almost there, I just need help over the line...

First Part:

If I do this:

```
firstday=$(date -d "-1 month -$(( $(date +%e) - 1 )) days")
echo $firstday
```

Then I get:

```
Fri May 1 16:09:51 AEST 2020
```

Which is the first day of the last month. However I want this in this format:

```
2020-05-01
```

Second Part:

If I do this:

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days"
```

That gives me:

```
Sun May 31 16:14:59 AEST 2020
```

However I need this in the format:

```
2020-05-31
```

Can someone please help me with how I can do this? I think these two commands will do what I want... it's probably just a format mask I need to get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the format of the output date, just add it to each `date` command: `+%Y-%m-%d`.

```
firstday=$(date -d "-1 month -$(( $(date +%e) - 1 )) days" +%Y-%m-%d)
echo $firstday
```

will output: `2020-05-01`

```
date -d "-$(date +%d) days" +%Y-%m-%d
```

will output: `2020-05-31`